# k8s nginx Ingress take my node IP as Address

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, metallb, bare-metal-server

I have 3 node k8s Cluster on my virtual env which is VMware Fusion.

[image: My Cluster Detail]

When try to create basic Ingress it takes my one node_ip which is nginx_controller running.

[image: Ingress Detail]

But 80 port is not open on all nodes. I mean it is not working

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.16.242.133 port 80: Connection refused
```

What I missing ?

- I installed Nginx Ingress Controller
- I installed MetalLB and configured it. It is working if I create service with type: LoadBalancer. It takes ExernalIp Ip and I can access it.
- I deploy basic app for test.
- I create a service for app. I can access on NodePort or CulesterIP. Both I tried.
- I create basic Ingress for manage hosts and routing staff. But this step I stuck.

My Questions ;

1-) Normaly what should Ingress take Ip as Address ? One of my node or External DHCP IP.

2-) When I create service with type: LoadBalancer it takes externalIP. I can record DNS to this IP and clients can access it. What is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 3):

Ingress supports two types of service type: `NodePort` and `LoadBalancer`.

While using `NodePort` service type you should use `nodeport` number instead of default port 80. Explanation to this behavior is available in [nginx ingress documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service):

> However, due to the container namespace isolation, a client located
> outside the cluster network (e.g. on the public internet) is not able
> to access Ingress hosts directly on ports 80 and 443. Instead, the
> external client must append the NodePort allocated to the
> ingress-nginx Service to HTTP requests.

So your curl should look like this:

```
curl 172.16.242.133:<node_port_number>
```

When you use `MetalLB` with `LoadBalancer` service type, it takes `externalIPs` from it's configuration that you specified when [installing metallb in cluster](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/).

More information about nginx ingress controller cooperation with metallb is available in [nginx documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#a-pure-software-solution-metallb).

> MetalLB requires a pool of IP addresses in order to be able to take
> ownership of the ingress-nginx Service. This pool can be defined in a
> ConfigMap named config located in the same namespace as the MetalLB
> controller. This pool of IPs must be dedicated to MetalLB's use, you
> can't reuse the Kubernetes node IPs or IPs handed out by a DHCP
> server.

Answer (score 1):

My Problem was,
I thought Ingress takes the IP and we record DNS to this IP. But It is not. Why Ingress object has **Address** and **Port** field I do not know. Just for information I guess but It is confusing for newbies.
Clients access the **Ingress Controller** not **Ingress**.

Actually **Ingress Controller Service** manages the externalIP or NodePort. So we have to configure this.

In my case nginx

```
kubectl edit service/ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
```

You can change type to LoadBalancer and you will get externalIP after configured the MetalLB. And define your Ingress objects, record DNS Records then you are ready.